# Java regex for URL

Tags: java, regex, url

I need an regex, which will  match the next urls:

```
(http|https)://(www)<my domain here>
(http|https)://(www)<my domain here>/page1
(http|https)://(www)<my domain here>/page1/.../
(http|https)://(www)<my domain here>/page1/...?a=b
(http|https)://(www)<my domain here>/page1/...?a=b&c=d...
```

I have one regex, but I don't know how to edit it

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?(\/[a-z0-9])*(\/?|(\?[a-z0-9]=[a-z0-9](&[a-z0-9]=[a-z0-9]*)?))$
```

For a specific domain name:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?example\.com(\/?|(\?[a-z0-9]=[a-z0-9](&[a-z0-9]=[a-z0-9]*)?))$
```

**Edit:** Validate domain and get Url:

```
(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?example\.com\S*
```

Comment: you don't understand me, I want to get only urls with specific domain name, e.g.:

http://www.example.org/...

Where I should put "example.org" in your regex?

Comment: @Sevak.Avet updated the answer.. i thought you wanted validations for `/page1/...?a=b..` etc.. :P

Comment: I mean, I want to get full URL with specific domain :) I want to validate only domain, but get full URL

Answer (score 1):

Try use this:

```
^(http|https):\/\/(www).([a-z\.]*)?(\/[a-z1-9\/]*)*\??([\&a-z1-9=]*)?
```

The explanation I get in site [Regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/).

```
/^(http|https):\/\/(www).([a-z\.]*)?(\/[a-z1-9\/]*)*\??([\&a-z1-9=]*)?/
    ^ assert position at start of the string
    1st Capturing group (http|https)
        1st Alternative: http
            http matches the characters http literally (case sensitive)
        2nd Alternative: https
            https matches the characters https literally (case sensitive)
    : matches the character : literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
    2nd Capturing group (www)
        www matches the characters www literally (case sensitive)
    . matches any character (except newline)
    3rd Capturing group ([a-z\.]*)?
        Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        [a-z\.]* match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
        \. matches the character . literally
    4th Capturing group (\/[a-z1-9\/]*)*
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
       \/ matches the character / literally
        [a-z1-9\/]* match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
            1-9 a single character in the range between 1 and 9
            \/ matches the character / literally
    \?? matches the character ? literally
        Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    5th Capturing group ([\&a-z1-9=]*)?
        Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
       [\&a-z1-9=]* match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \& matches the character & literally
            a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
            1-9 a single character in the range between 1 and 9
            = the literal character =
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^https?://[^/@]*\.domain\.com(/.*)?$
```